# How to use same Onedrive service object in different files of Android project?

Tags: android, onedrive

I am using Onedrvie SDK for my android project.I have successfully login and get the elements from onedrive in one of my fragament. I need to use the same IOneDriveClient oject (IOneDriveClient ) in another file. How I can achieve this? I am using folllowing code.. Simply I want to create "oneDriveClient" in one activity and want use the same from other activites (fragments)...

```
final IClientConfig oneDriveConfig = new DefaultClientConfig.createWithAuthenticators(
                                        msaAuthenticator,
                                        adalAuthenticator);

final IOneDriveClient oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient
                                        .Builder()
                                        .fromConfig(oneDriveConfig)
                                        .loginAndBuildClient(getActivity());
```